# HERE API 6.2 vs 7.0 for AutoComplete

Tags: here-api

I am trying to replace using Google Maps Autocomplete service with HERE API. I basically just want an autocomplete that would suggestion State, City or Zip Codes as the user types.

One thing that I think is odd is the [Geocoder Autocomplete API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html) is in maintenance mode and they suggest to use the new [Geocoder and Search API v7](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-geocode-address.html) but I am not liking the results as much as the v6.2 version - unless I am doing something wrong.

An example with the 6.2 version - searching for "New":

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apiKey=YOURAPIKEY&query=New&resultType=city&country=usa
```

I am getting 5 results:

- United States, NY, New York, New York
- United States, LA, New Orleans
- United States, NJ, Newark
- United States, CA, Newport Beach
- United States, CT, New Haven, New Haven

When I try to do the same thing in the 7.0 version I get nothing back and have to search for "New Y":

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=New%20Y&apiKey=APIKEY&in=countryCode:USA
```

I then only get 1 result:

- NY, United States

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong with the new API or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the discover or autosuggest endpoints instead of the geocode one.

Comment: I am also seeing what you are suggesting, I'll file a ticket with them to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the autosuggest endpoint:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html

https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?q=New&apiKey=<>&at=40.7128,74.0060

this will do what you want but note that it requires at/in attributes to be filled.